# Multiple objects appeared together - highest number of times

Tags: sql, r, oracle, excel, data-analysis

I have basically query join conditions in a normal oracle database log kind of table.

```
query_id, join_condition
1         schema1.table1.col1=schema2.table2.col1
1         schema1.table1.col2=schema2.table2.col2
1         schema1.table1.col1=schema2.table3.col1
2         schema1.table1.col1=schema2.table2.col1
2         schema1.table1.col1=schema2.table3.col1
2         schema1.table1.col1=schema3.table3.col1
...........
.........
.......
```

I have blown it out into an excel sheet like this

```
query_id, left_schema, left_table, left_column, right_schema, right_table, right_schema
1         schema1       table1       col1        schema2       table2       col1
1         schema1       table1       col2        schema2       table2       col2
................
..............
.........
```

I wanted to answer below question from these.

All the tables combinations used in same query - display in sorted order of number of times they appeared together.

I have solved it by putting up union of left table and right table in sorted order format into a table and grouped it. So there are randomly combinations of 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 table names based on each query ids number of tables.

Now my next question is, how do i find all possible permutations and combinations of these tables in sorted order. For example in query id 1, we have table1 joined on table2, table3. So this query id falls in 3 tables combination bucket. But also (table1, table2) and (table1, table3) falls in 2 tables combination bucket. Similarly there may be 4 tables together, 5 tables together buckets. I am not able to solve this in SQL or excel. Do you have any suggestions for solving this. Do graph databases/R statistical methods can be of some purpose here along with visualizations. sorry for long question.

Desired output should be 4 sets of reports.
1)Two tables together in sorted order of number of occurrences together

```
two_tables_combination, number_of_queryids
schema1.table1-schema2.table2               2
schema1.table1-schema2.table3               2
schema1.table1-schema3.table3               1
```

2)Three tables together in sorted order of number of occurrences together

```
three_tables_combination,                      number_of_occurances
schema1.table1-schema2.table2-schema2.table3               2
schema1.table1-schema2.table3-schema3.table3               1
```

3)Four tables together in sorted order of number of occurrences together
4)any combination of tables which are highly used.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Desired output is 4 sets of reports, 1)2 tables together in sorted order of number of occurrences together 2)3 tables together in sorted order of number of occurrences together 3)4 tables together in sorted order of number of occurrences together 4)any combination of tables which are highly used.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and put this desired output in tabular format? It is difficult to read a comment.

Comment: Thanks. Added more details.

Comment: Does the order really matter?  Shouldn't `table1 join table2` count the same as `table2 join table1`?  If you remove sorting from this question then [DBMS_FREQUENT_ITEMSETS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_frqist.htm) might be a perfect solution.

Comment: Thanks jonearles. It works up to some extent. Great suggestion.